# Set UserControl DataContext Binding from within a ListView's ItemTemplate in xaml

Tags: .net, xaml, win-universal-app

I'm trying to implement a user control within a ListView's ItemTemplate. Basically there's a list within a list -first list is being presented using the general listview, second is presented using a user control within each item of the first list.

So anyway, I'm trying to bind the user control to the item, but my intellisense is going all nuts (everything is getting covered with those squiggly red lines) and I'm getting a 'The property 'Value' was not found in type WindowsUIXamlBindingWrapper.

```
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
     <ctrls:RandomUserCtrl x:Name="m_RandomcUserCtrl" DataContext="{Binding}" 
      Visibility="{Binding Path=IsActive,Converter={StaticResource TrueToVisibleConverter}}"/>
   </DataTemplate>
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, give your ListView a unique name, and do `{Binding DataContext.IsActive, ElementName=YourListViewName, Converter={StaticResource TrueToVisibleConverter}}` or use relativesource to reach out and grab it instead.

Comment: I've thought of that, but wouldn't I then I'd get the 1st list instead of the first list's currently iterated item, which is my intention?

Comment: The IsActive is actually another property of an item in the first("parent") list,